# Using Spring WebSocket's SimpMessagingTemplate with multi endpoint configuration

Tags: java, spring, websocket, spring-websocket, spring-4

I'm using Spring 4.3.5 and WebSocket with SockJS, STOMP and SimpleBrokerMessageHandler.

In my application I have three separate WebSocket endpoints running on a different address: ***/endPointA, /ednpointB, /endpointC*** 
To be even more specific, I have three separate configuration classes annotated with @Configuration @EnableWebSocketMessageBroker annotations.

I also have a Class that has @Autowired SimpMessagingTemplate.

Finally I have three clients, each connected to one, different EndPoint. 
All of them, however are subscribed to the "same" channel address which is */topic/messages*

- ClientOne is connected **endpointA**
- ClientTwo is connected **endpointB**
- ClientThree is connected **endpointC**

When I use **SimpMessagingTemplate** to send something to */topic/messages*, then all clients receives this message.

After that I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to "isolate" the web Socket endpoints so the message will not be propagated to all endpoints?
2. Why is this actually happening here?

I did some investigation (heap dump analysis) and I found that for my configuration I have:

- Three instances of **SimpMessagingTemplate**, However I'm using always the same one instance to send a message (because of @Autowire - additionaly I'm printing SimpMessagingTemplate.toString()).
- One instance of **SimpleBrokerMessageHandler**
- Three instances of **SockJsWebSocketHandler**

So I wonder, if this message propagation over all endpoits is a "feature" of SimpleBrokerMessageHandler or SimpMessagingTemplate.

Comment: I have a similar issue. Can you recall how you resolved this?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately we didn't. We accept the reality - it was proof of concept app. Although I'm still curious what was the reason behind it.

Comment: Reason depends on your configuration. Possibly all the clients were subscribed to the same topic. Instead, they should be subscribed to their respective *queues*

Comment: Yes there were subscribed to the same topic, although I thought that there is a topic isolation between endpoints with different names.

Comment: Na, messaging does not work that way. Isolation can be done through dedicated queues.

Answer (score 3):

I facing the same issue in a multi-tenant application that I solved thanks to [this thread](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/4469) :

My websocket endpoint is: `ws://127.0.0.1/my-context-app/ws`
, java config file is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

   @Override
   public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {       
      registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOrigins("*");
      registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS(); 
   }
}
```

My websocket queues url forms are prefixed by tenant-id: `/[tenant-id]/[url-of-queue]`.

Each client subscribe on its own tenant-id. It can not subscribe to queue of another client thanks to `WebSocketSecurityConfig.configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry)` method and a custom spring bean which has a 'websocket-queue-subscription-security-check' method :

```
@Configuration
public class WebSocketSecurityConfig extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    protected void configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) {
        messages
          .simpSubscribeDestMatchers("/**")
          .access("@customWSSecurityCheck.isSubscriptionAllowed(authentication, message)");
    }

}
```

My custom bean named customWSSecurityCheck check if authenticated user is allowed to subscribe on queue. Keep in mind that `CustomAuthentication` implements `org.springframework.security.core.Authentication` with additional tenantId attribute that is filled by additional code not mentioned there on a custom spring security filter / authentication method:

```
@Bean()
public class CustomWSSecurityCheck {

    public boolean isSubscriptionAllowed(CustomAuthentication authentication, Message message) {

       StompHeaderAccessor sha = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(message);
       String url = sha.getDestination().substring(1);
       String tenantId = url.substring(0, url.indexOf("/"));

       return tenantId.equals(authentication.getTenantId());
    }
}
```

Of course It involve that every message sended by the server should be prefixed by the right tenant-id: `MessagingService.convertAndSend("[tenant-id]/[url-of-queue]", messagePayload)`